# why (* 1.1 1.1) is 1.2100000000000002 in racket?

Tags: scheme, racket

When I try the following in racket:

```
(* 1.1 1.1)
```

why does it return

```
1.2100000000000002
```

instead of

```
1.21
```

while

```
(* 1.2 1.2) ; is 1.44, as expected
```

#### Edit

and the following returns false:

```
(= (* 1.1 1.1) 1.21); #f
```

Comment: If you want exact arithmetic, use exact math, not floating point.

Comment: This is an issue not specific to Racket, but to any programming language that has floating point numbers. See http://www.floating-point-gui.de/ for explanations

Comment: thanks for the website, great resource!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Oh look, this compares correctly!

```
> (= (* #e1.1 #e1.1) #e1.21)
#t
```

(Racket has this really nice feature that `#e1.1` is actually read in as exactly 1.1. Other Scheme implementations do not necessarily work that way, and may actually read in `#e1.1` as floating-point first and then convert to exact.)

Anyway, to elaborate on everybody else's point, without an exactness specifier, Scheme treats a number literal with a dot in it as inexact<sup>†</sup> (that is, `1.1` and `#i1.1` read in as the same thing). And with inexact numbers, you cannot really expect sane results when doing "exact" comparisons (such as `=`).

<sup>†</sup> R7RS, section 6.2.5: "If the written representation of a number has no exactness preﬁx, the constant is inexact if it contains a decimal point or an exponent. Otherwise, it is exact."

Comment: thanks for summarizing, I am sorry I don't have enough reputation to up-vote your answer : )